# Python3 six - AttributeError: custom object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, six

I have a list of `dict` objects of type `Case` which are initiated with a `dict`.
When running in Python2, I could loop over keys and values, to facilitate both Python versions I'm using the `six` library.

```
class Case:

    def __init__(self, obj):

        properties = {}
        # standardize Boolean properties
        true_values = ['1', 1, True, 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES']
        false_values = ['0', 0, False, 'no', 'No', 'NO']
        for (k, v) in iteritems(properties):
            # standardize TRUE values
            if v in true_values:
                properties[k] = True
            # standardize FALSE values
            elif v in false_values:
                properties[k] = False
            # keep String values
            elif isinstance(v, str):
                continue

        # remove NULL values
        filtered = {k: v for (k, v) in iteritems(properties) if v != None}

        # set Case instance attribute for each property
        for (k, v) in iteritems(filtered):
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__.get(key, None)

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

When I loop over this list, I get an AttributeError despite following `six` [documentation](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#iterating-through-dict-keys-values-items).

I iterate through a list of above objects:

```
from six import iteritems

def transform(case_list):
    for case in case_list:
        for (key, value) in iteritems(case): #crashes here
            #do stuff
```

But get an AttributeError every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app/run.py", line 134, in <module>
main()
File "/home/user/other.py", line 55, in transform
for (key, value) in iteritems(case):
File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py3.4.egg/six.py", line 581, in iteritems
return iter(d.items(**kw))
AttributeError: 'Case' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I call it with `python3 app/run.py`. Why does it not recognize the iterable?

Comment: Your error message is coming from some completely different code you haven't shown us, where you're trying to apply `iteritems` to a `Case` object.

Comment: Line 55 is in method `transform`. The other method just calls `transform` with parameter is a list of `Case`s? Sorry I don't get your hint, can you elaborate?

Comment: `six.iteritems()` is meant for objects that have an `.items()` method (ie dictionaries) and your Case object does not have such a method. Implement that method and it will work.

Comment: Oh, wait, you did post `transform`. You say "dict objects of type Case", but `Case` objects are not any sort of dict. They don't support the operations required by `six.iteritems`.

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson : thanks I found a solution, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding a `items()` method to Case class:

```
    def items(self):
        return zip(self.__dict__.values(), self.__dict__.keys())
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what you want and also gives random ordering of keys and values.  Instead you should rely on `self.__dict__.items()`